Are there any chemical concerns with Blue Monster pipe thread sealant coming into contact with Loctite spray foam?
Looking at spraying the foam near to where water pipes have a thick coating of Blue Monster and wasn't sure if I should be concerned about interactions.

not if it is dry

Have you flame tested this spray foam?  A lot of it is Really Really BAD. Ask the Browns Ferry nuclear plant or Sunshine Mine staff. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdItsso3ur0

The loctite product is made for use around plumbing pipes, so it would be unusual that another product made for plumbing would be incompatible.
You could tape over the Blue Monster to be sure the 2 products would not touch.
If you are still very concerned about a reaction you can reach Loctite @ : (860) 571-5100 and ask them.
